# Short Story Identification - Boy Dismantling a Radio

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to identify a very short story (maybe four pages) about a boy trying to figure out how radio works, finally dismantling the machine to discover a small news reporter inside...

I've read in 1980s in a Czech translation. The original language is most likely English or Russian.

Answer (score 7):

It could be **[The Little Warranty People](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Little-Warranty-People-Eduard-Uspensky/dp/0679820639)** by **Eduard Uspensky**, originally published in **1974** ([Wikipedia, Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8))

> The warranty people, small people who live in and take care of
> appliances under warranty, must defend themselves against a curious
> little girl and an army of mice

There is a **News Man, living inside the radio set**.
And there is a very curious girl (not a boy), that saw once those "little warranty people" and so tries to find them again (but it seems she never disassembles the radio).

**News Man** is also referred as a Radio Man, and he is repairing all kinds of a radio devices. He has a radio set of his own, and it is actually disassembled (without a box).

[image: Cover of "The Little Warranty People" by Eduard Uspensky (illustrated by Vladimir Shpitalnik). The cover shows a man in a suit, a mouse, and a little girl inside the gears of a clock.]

[Full story (Russian)](https://vseskazki.su/eduard-uspenskij/garantijnye-chelovechki.html)